# Where is the Clear constraints?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, constraints

Where is the 'Clear constraints' located in the menu other than the 'resolve auto layout issues'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the menu:
Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Clear constrains

At the storyboard itself:
On the bottom right part of the screen, near the object library, tap the first icon and there it is.

[image]

Comment: I know that one, the thing is, where can I find it in the menu